# Looping over array in GET request

Tags: zapier

I'm trying to build a Zap in Zapier that will

1. Perform at single GET request that will return a JSON object.
2. Loop over a key in that object that contains an array.
3. POST a value from each array element to another URL.

I initially tried doing this with native Zapier elements, but I'm not sure how to take an action on each array item. I read in the Zapier Code documentation:

> Setting the output to an array of objects will run the subsequent
>   steps multiple times — once for each object in the array.

So now I'm doing the GET request in a Code element:

```
fetch('https://domain.com/path', { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'} })
    .then(function(res) {
        return res.json();
    }).then(function(json) {
        if (typeof json.arrayElem == 'object') {
          callback(json.arrayElem);
        } else {
          callback([]);
        }
    }).catch(callback);
```

This code returns an error:

> Bargle. We hit an error creating a run javascript. :-( Error:  [object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

I think I'm close, though, because if I change `callback(json.arrayElem);` to `callback(json);` I get the same error but with a single `[object Object]` instead of multiple.

Anyone have any pointers? I'm not married to using the Code element, but perfectly happy to if it will do what I need it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be returning proper callback arguments - the first argument is an `Error` or `null`.

Bad:

```
callback(json.arrayElem);
```

Good:

```
callback(null, json.arrayElem);
```

Same case for `callback([])` vs. `callback(null, [])`.